# onResume() equivalent for Fragments in Android

Tags: android, fragment, onresume

I am working on an application that does http requests to a server.

I have a TabBarController extending FragmentActivity that controls the fragments through 3 buttons. Each button shows a specific fragment and hides the others.

I want to do a http request every time I open one of those fragments. I tried using onResume in the fragment I want this to happen, however it won't work unless the TabBarController activity pauses first.

I tried searching things about this but nothing I found worked.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragments are still running when you hide them, so having checks in onResume() would not work.

You can instead do something like

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
  super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
  if (isVisibleToUser) {
    // onResume() equivalent here
    // send HTTP request or ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me. This will never be called. Neither on creation nor when it comes to foreground (e.g. after back press)

Comment: @Bevor on Fragment creation or resume, the Fragment's `onResume()` would still be called. The `setUserVisibleHint` would only let you know that the tab itself has been selected, and you'll need to handle both cases.